# Linux mv command move all files to sub folder

Tags: linux

I want to move all folders from within a folder named public to it's parent folder.

public\public\200 folders

I have tried `mv public ~/site/storage/app/public` but get the error **Directory not empty**.

What am I missing? Thanks I'm new to Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `mv public/* ~/site/storage/app/public`! The `*` selects all the files inside the public directory.